# How can I check the AngularJS controller from within the template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular's [**UI-Router**](https://ui-router.github.io/) as shown below to do URL-routing in my web-app as shown below:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState1', {
    url: '/state1',
    templateUrl: 'state1.html',
    controller: 'MyState1Ctrl'
  });

$stateProvider.state('myState2', {
    url: '/state2',
    templateUrl: 'state2.html',
    controller: 'MyState2Ctrl'
  });
```

Within each of the two template files `state1.html`, `state2.html`, I have my navigation bar directive: `<myapp-navigation-bar></myapp-navigation-bar>`

But I want the navigation bar to behave differently based on weather it is in `myState1` or `myState2`. How can I detect from within the controller of the navigation bar (or its template) which state it is in?

Comment: A [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) should help you to share data between controllers/components.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to add an attribute in this directive to tell which state the navigation bar is currently in.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)**, You can do this,

```
.controller('MyState1Ctrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.statecurrent = $state.current;
});
```

Comment: From within the controller of the navigation bar (not the state's controller), how can I tell if I'm in State1 or State2?

Comment: you mean maincontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check like this -

```
.controller('MyState1Ctrl', function($scope, $state) {
        if ($state.is("myState1")) {
          //Add Logic
        }
});
```

Comment: From within the controller of the navigation bar (not the state's controller), how can I tell if I'm in State1 or State2?